# Why Connected App's client_id and client_secret still valid after a sandbox refresh?

Tags: connected-apps, sandbox-refresh, client-id

Imagine you have a Connected App `foo`

I've noticed that even after refreshing a sandbox, you are still able to use the `client_id` and `client_secret` of the `foo` Connected App of that sandbox before it was refreshed.

Even though after the refresh, the `client_id` and `client_secret` of `foo` are completely different.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure the Connected App was created in **that** sandbox, and not elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: 18 days after, I'm still able to call the Connected App of the environment which was refresh.

Comment: That seems contrary to what I'd expect. You might want to contact support, since I'm pretty sure that's not supposed to happen.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I got a reply from SFDC support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After getting contact with Salesforce Support they answered that this can occur and that it also is 'working as designed', even though it is indeed a grey area, with no documentation that covers this detail.

Below you can check the answer from the support.

> Hi Leandro,
>
> The issue was strange even for us and it turned out to be working as
>   designed after consulting with our R&D Team. when you refresh the
>   sandbox the client Id and Client secret gets changed and you will be
>   still able to use old values which should not be in actual.
>
> While we specified this as working as designed we will continue to
>   learn about how our customers are using the product and make
>   adjustments for future releases. We understood that this scenario is
>   grey area which is not fully documented.Our product has created a User
>   story(feature request) in order to remove the old values from the
>   backend.This might get implemented in the upcoming releases
>
> I hope you understand.Let me know if you need any further assistance
>   from my end
>
> Thanks and regards,

Comment: Interesting. I still wouldn't recommend relying on the behavior, though. At least, until it's documented.